# How to send email to List in sharepoint 2010 - by default email for list is not permitted on the system

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a requirement in sharepoint 2010 custom list(customised infopath form).

I want to send an email to custom list

the following fields i want to map

Subject - Title

From ID in Outlook 2010 - Submitted by

Body of the message in Outlook 2010 - Description

Attachment - Attachment

Start date - received date

What tools I should use? some input to build will help.